# Powershell serial communication to teraterm

Tags: powershell, serial-port

I'm trying to create a powershell script that sends a string from 1 COM port to another one. The string should show up in a teraterm screen of the receiving port. But I can't get it to work, although it should be straight forward.
The teraterm screen is just blank.

Setup:
I have 2 usb serial adapter (COM3, COM4), both connected with a physical serial cable.
[image: teraterm setup new-line]
[image: setup 2]

The powershell code:

```
[System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]::getportnames()
#prints COM1 COM3 COM4

$STX = [char] 2
$ETX = [char] 3

$port= new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM4,9600,None,8,one
$port.open()
$port.Write("Hello world\r\n")
$port.close()

$port.open()
$port.Write("Hello world\n")
$port.close()

$port.open()
$port.Write("Hello world\r")
$port.close()

$port.open()
$port.WriteLine("Hello world")
$port.close()

$port.open()
$port.WriteLine($STX+"Hello world"+$ETX)
$port.close()

read-host
```

Anything I missed or any pointers?

Extra info:
Also tried sending strings with CMD and C#
**We were able to send a string from an old handheld device (so cable is fine)**

Comment: Have you tried plugging in the handheld and sending data to COM4, and then doing `$Port.Open();$Port.ReadExisting();$Port.Close()` to see if you are able to read from the port? With it being a USB adapter PowerShell may not be seeing it like you would expect, so you may be sending data into nothing.

Comment: The string `"Hello world\r\n"`... do you get a different response if you try ``"Hello world`r`n"``. Backtick is the PowerShell escape character.

Comment: @Matt doesn't change still no response

Comment: This blog just craps all over `IO.Ports.SerialPort` as being largely unreliable. http://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport. Still reading but it talks about using the WinAPI instead. Have you tried to read and send bytes instead?

Comment: This might also help. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2006/10/10/top-5-serialport-tips-kim-hamilton/. I cannot test any of this as I dont have the setup for it.

Comment: I suggest setting up a VM (using VirtualBox, VMPlayer, etc.) and giving it a COM port. The virtual COM port can be connected to one of the hosts physical COM ports. Then debug your PS code, whether it be [System.IO.Ports.SerialPort] or WinAPI. Once you've got it working use your USB adapters. Also, folks answering the question on SO might be more inclined to try this themselves if they know they don't need a particular USB serial device.

Comment: @Χpẘ I doubt it the PS code, maybe it's pc related (java comm, c++)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the driver for the USB convertors were bad. I fixed the issue with virtual serial ports. Also note that in my situation I had to use a `Ctrl + c` (ETX) to send the message.

```
$port= new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM3,9600,None,8,one
$ETX = [char] 3
$port.open()
$port.WriteLine('Hello')
$port.Write($ETX)
$port.Close()
```

Comment: What is ETX, and why would that be required?